# Sanitize using filter_var_array - prevent NULL from turning into empty string

Tags: php, sanitization

I have a MySQL result that I want to safely output using PHP, i.e. converting special characters such as `<` to `&lt;`.

filter_var_array works fine, except that `NULL` values turn into empty string `''`.

I still want them to be NULL in order to reflect the MySQL value and to test with `is_null()` etc.

```
$sql_rows = filter_var_array($sql_rows, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
foreach ($sql_rows as $sql_row) {
    print '<li>' . $sql_row['name'] . '</li>';
}
```

Any convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no magic way of doing that. You need to process each variable manually

Comment: You need a custom function then. `filter_var` is all about cleaning **string** variables.

Comment: For the record, your NULLs are being converted to strings not because of filter_var_array, but because you always get strings back when querying a mysql database, no matter the type they actually are. Most of the time this not noticeable because unless you tell PHP otherwise it will magically cast the types to whatever fits, eg a numeric string to an integer, but this has its gotchas :)

Comment: @Mahn, you can most certainly get php type null back from a mysql result set. I've done it with PDO and mysqli. Yes, real type null like `$row['foo'] === null`.

Comment: @rambocoder is correct, results are returned using MDB2 as a mysqli abstraction layer, and MySQL type NULL becomes PHP type null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql_rows = array_map(function($val){
    return is_null($val) ? null : filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}, $sql_rows);
```

Comment: What about something like this, does it look okay/efficient? `function sanitize_custom_single($input) { return is_null($input) ? null : filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS); }` and `function sanitize_custom_array($input) { array_walk_recursive($input, 'sanitize_custom_single'); return $input; }`

Comment: Hmm. Manual page for `array_walk_recursive` says "Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function.". Maybe ths is better: `function sanitize_custom_array($input) { if (is_array($input)) { return array_map('sanitize_custom_array', $input); } else { return is_null($input) ? null : filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS); } }`

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, when a NULL value is selected from MySQL, PHP interprets it as a blank character. I would just process and output each row in one loop; you'll have more control as to what is happening to each value, and it will be more efficient.

```
foreach($sql_rows as $sql_row)
{
    $output = "<li>";

    if(!empty($sql_row['name']))
    {
        $output .= htmlspecialchars($sql_row['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= "<strong>NULL</strong>";
    }

    $output .= "</li>";

    echo $output;
}
```